# how to find wordpress files on linux installed from bitnami

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress

super frustrated by this problem. I am trying to learn wordpress development and I have been trying for hours to find the files I need such as functions.php but alas I can not find the files

Does anyone know where functions.php and other wordpress files would be on linux installed from bitnami?

I have found /opt/lampp/var/mysql but I can not access it with the permissions it has.

I have tried changing the permissions using chmod but I still can not get into it.

Comment: `/opt/lampp/var/mysql` sounds more like the database installation, though that would be a pretty strange location to put such thing. Looks like that installation ignores the system it finds more or less and installs everything once more. Not a good thing. What you should look for is your http servers host configuration, that will tell you where the documents are kept. Or you simply use standard utilities like `locate` or `find` to search for files. Have a look at their "man pages" to learn how to use them.

Comment: Oh, and probably it is not a good idea to play around with the file permissions unless you really know what you are doing. You will break things. Instead you should assume an identity that does have the required permission to access files you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

it's under apps/wordpress/

The following is from their readme file.

```
apache2/: Apache Web server.
        varnish/: Varnish Cache
    php/: PHP Scripting Language.
    mysql/: MySQL Database.
    apps/
      wordpress/: WordPress application folder
        conf/: WordPress Apache configuration files
        htdocs/: WordPress PHP application files
      phpMyAdmin/: phpMyAdmin application folder (optional)
```

Comment: I see that folder now but I do not see any php files that seem like I could change anything in wordpress.